# Excel using a range of cells to return value corresponding to an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using Excelsius 2008 (Excel 2007 plus a dashboard builder) to create dashboards and publish them as webpages.

I have a range of cells `A1:A20` that number from 1 to 20. Then Next to it I have `B1:B20` that consists of texts (e.g. B1 may have 'High Level", and B2 may have "Low Level", etc.).

I also have indicators on my dashboard. The indicator button image has a label which can be shown when you hover over it (almost like a tool tip message box). Right now the label on the indicator can display a value in the message box with any number from `A1:A20` because I have a single cell referencing it (`C9`). That cell has a vlookup as such:

```
 =VLOOKUP(C9,$A$1:$B$20,1,TRUE)
```

But I am trying to make it so if a 6 appears in the cell (`C9`) and when I hover over the icon I should get the text value from `B6` not `A6`.  I am merely using the `Column A` to match the number in `C9` and if they match, then the adjacent cell's (in `Column B`) text appears.

Can this be done with look up functions or any other command that excel has?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you always have to write walls of text? There's a handy key called 'Enter' or 'Return', you know?

Comment: Im sorry, I will adjust the way i ask questions in the future to make it more clear for viewers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your equation to `=VLOOKUP(C9,$A$1:$B$20,2,TRUE)` should pull in the value of column B

Comment: Is it possible the match to be with 3 columns. Lets say column A has the numbers 1 -60. Column B as the description, and column C has the module number since there are many. Can a vlookup connect all 3 or wiil i have to integrate a Match command inside the vlookup?

Comment: Actually, forget column C how do I return column A and B instead of just returning column B?

Comment: I'd look to 'CONCATENATE'
"=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(D8,$A$2:$C21,2,TRUE)," ",VLOOKUP(D8,$A$2:$C21,3,TRUE))'